# Not displaying symbols in vim-airline

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-airline

My vim-airline has an unexpected `?` symbol next to the program being run:
[image]

I have tried manually setting the airline_symbols [from here](https://github.com/tracyone/t-vim/blob/master/rc/airline.vim), for ex:
`let g:airline_left_sep = '>'` and so on but this does not seem to do anything about the `?` symbols next to vim and utf-8 on the right hand side.

As you can see from the rc file (below), I have also done `let g:airline_section_y = ''` but this does not seem to be removing the utf-8 tag from the airline bar.

How can I fix this?

This is my rc file (excluding plugins because it is too long):

```
" Color Schemes and Themes
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme toast
highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
highlight nonText ctermbg=NONE
let g:airline_theme='deus'
let g:airline_section_y = ''
let g:airline_section_z = '(%l,%c)'

" Basic Vim Settings
set number
set relativenumber
set autoindent
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set softtabstop=4
set mouse=a

" NERDTree Keybindings
" <C-t> refers to <control+t>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
set encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: I believe this symbol is `g:airline_right_sep`. What is the result of `:echo g:airline_right_sep`?

Comment: Setting `g:airline_right_sep` to my .vimrc does not fix this. It adds the '<' as a separator between the different sections and you can see it but the `?` symbol still remains exactly where it was.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
let g:airline_symbols_ascii = 1
let g:airline_right_alt_sep = '>'
let g:airline_right_sep = '<'
```

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of why you would do this? (Like me, you probably suspect a font issue?)

Comment: Your "I would try `<vimsrcipt>`" answers keep piling up in the low quality posts queue. Maybe add some explanation to satisfy SE's algorithm?

Comment: @Friedrich Thanks for telling me :-) I try first to find what is the problem. Without being able to reproduce it :-/